# Robe JS cannot run on my node

Tags: javascript, node.js

from the tutorial...
app.js --->

```
"use strict"

var som = require('robe');


var xxx = yield som.connect('localhost');
```

---

to execute node --harmony app.js

```
$ node --harmony app.js
/Users/admin/project/test/app.js:6
var xxx = yield som.connect('localhost');
          ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
at startup (node.js:124:16)
at node.js:807:3
```

it will either unexpected 'yield' or 'class'
node version 0.11.15
anyone know what happen or solution?

Comment: same here... Didn't found a solution yet...

Comment: Please see. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414973/unexpected-strict-mode-reserved-word-yield-node-v0-11-harmony-es6

Same set of issues, resolved! :)